# Problem in Datetime conversion in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem while converting a string whose value is `dd.mm.yyyy` to `DateTime` in c#

```
string OriginalDateFormat = "28.06.2009";
DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime(OriginalDateFormat);
```

Throwing an exception `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

But if it is in `mm.dd.yyyy` then it is running fine.

I googled and got lots of sites but all in vain

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx? Google is not the best tool for something like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the exact format string:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("28.06.2009", "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If this is the value is from user input, you probably want to use DateTime.TryParseExact so you can handle failure gracefully:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("28.06.2009", "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                        DateTimeStyles.None, // Default formatting options
                        out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully parsed {0}", dt);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Did not recognise date");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think its an issue with culture...The format you specified is (I think) GB and the default culture is US.
 You will need to specify the culture also.

Instead try this:

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);//en-Us or en-GB not sure

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(p, culture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```